# Google GeoCharts - Loading Slow

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps, google-visualization

I am creating marker based google geocharts. But it is taking lots of time load **entire city data** .

My code
**HTML**

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCXy0BKw58SlhIj-KHgtu3IGSk8JV8X2JI" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
  <script>
  google.charts.load('current', {
   callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonp.json);
   });
    var options = {
      region: 'US',
      displayMode: 'markers',
      colorAxis:{
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue:600,
        colors:['#106393','#F4FB94']
      },
    resolution: 'provinces'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
},
packages:['geochart']
});
```

**jsonp.json** I am having around 1000 no. of rows or data.

```
{
 cols: [{id: 'A', label: 'City', type: 'string'},
     {id: 'B', label: 'Occurances', type: 'number'},

 ],
 rows: [{c:[{v: 'new york'},
         {v: 555},

    ]},
     {c:[{v: 'salt lake city'},
         {v: 541},

    ]},
     {c:[{v: 'charlottesville'},
         {v: 333},

    ]}
],
}
```

Is there any way to load it faster??

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @WhiteHat Yes. That's the trouble for me.

Comment: there is lookup process to find the location on the map based on the name value, using [lng / lat] or zip code _could_ make a difference but documentation says longer names are better for `'markers'` mode...